# Issue in query(ordering products)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I want to order products by price with one link for low to high and the other high to low, But after I click "low to high" or "high to low" the order is not changing, it stays on the same page but the url is changing.
I tried to debug the query and I got: "select * from `products` where `categorie_id` = ? order by `price` asc" is that means that it can't find the id from categories table?
if it is, I can't find whats the problem

this is the function in the controller:

```
public function products(Request $request, $category_url, $sort= 'ASC')
{
    Product::getProducts($category_url, self:: $data);

    if ( $category1 = Categorie::where('url', '=', $category_url)->first() ) {

        $products = Product::where('categorie_id', $category1->getAttribute('id'))->orderBy('price', $sort)->get();

        return view('content.products', self::$data , compact('products', 'sort')); 
    }
}
```

this is the route:

```
  Route::get('shop/{category_url}/sorting-{sort?}', 'ShopController@products');
```

those are the link from the view, the view is content.products

```html
  <a href="  {{ url('shop/'.$category['url'].'/sorting-asc')}}" style="color:black"> High to low</a> |
  <a href="  {{ url('shop/'.$category['url'].'/sorting-desc')}}" style="color:black">Low to high</a>
```

the model:

```
class Product extends Model {


static public function getProducts($category_url, &$data){

    $data['products']=$data['category']=[];


    if ($category=Categorie::where('url','=', $category_url)->first()){

        $category= $category->toArray();
        $data['category']=$category;
        $data['title']=$data['title']. ' | ' . $category['title'];


        if ($products=Categorie::find( $category['id'])->products){

            $data['products']= $products->toArray();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I would do it:

```
public function products(Request $request, $category_url, $sort= 'ASC'){

    $category1 = Categorie::where('url', '=', $category_url)->first();
    $products = Product::where('categorie_id', $category1->id)->orderBy('price', $sort)->get();
    return view('content.products', ['products' => $products, 'sort' => $sort, 'category' => $category1]); 
}
```

Comment: in this way I Get Undefined variable: category (View: C:\xampp5\htdocs\myshop\resources\views\content\products.blade.php)

Comment: so I tried to add this : https://pastebin.com/BZrfuwRK but then it still not changing the order

Comment: I just edited previus answer. Added parameter category.